# How can I prove a language is context-free if I remove one character from its alphabet?

Tags: compiler-construction, computation, compiler-theory

Suppose that we have a language L that is context free,and 'a' among others belongs to its alphabet. How can I prove that the language ERASEa(L),that removes all instances of the character 'a' in the strings produced by L (f.e. abbac -> bbc), is still context-free? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume that this problem comes from a course you are taking or self-studying. It's hard to believe that your textbook doesn't contain at least some hints about how to construct this proof, but it's easy enough to find references online. You might start with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_operations#String_substitution) and the following section. (The proof consists of constructing a grammar for the new language by modifying the old grammar, and then proving that the constructed grammar is correct.)

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be that if L is a context free language, there exists some grammar G = (V, Σ, R, S).  The set of terminals, V, and the start symbol, S, remain unchanged. The set of terminals, Σ, becomes Σ' = Σ - 'a'. Finally, the set of production rule relations R = V -> (V ∪ Σ)* is modified so that R' = V -> (V ∪ Σ')* where the rules in R' are just those in R with 'a' removed.  Since G' = (V, Σ', R', S) is a valid CFG, the L without 'a' is a context free language.